# "お手伝いできますか？" used to ask for help

Tags: politeness, set-phrases

Is this a natural combination of phrases when asking for help when you are lost somewhere?

> 道に迷ってるんですけど、お手伝いできますか？

My gut feeling is the "お手伝いできますか" part is awkward and sounds like a literal  translation from "Can you help?" in English.

Would it be more natural to replace this with "手伝ってもらえませんか？"

Also, I feel the "お手伝い" form is typically used when you are helping someone else, as in ”お手伝いしましょうか”. How natural is it to use this form when requesting someone's help?

Update: corrected typo in the original phrase that Chocolate pointed out.

Comment: お手伝いできますか sounds more like "Can I help you?"

Comment: @chocolate: Do you think the listener would even be able to figure this out? I guess maybe from context they could guess that the person is looking for help.

Comment: The 街 is a typo for 道, right?

Comment: Yes, I just corrected it. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think it would be understood from the context that you're looking for help, but it would sound unnatural... (and maybe a bit impolite...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

お手伝いできますか sounds more like "Can I help you?"

手伝ってもらえませんか？ would be fine for asking for help, but in your particular situation I'd go for:

> 道に迷ってるんですけど、ちょっと教えてもらえますか？
>   道に迷ったんですけど、ちょっと教えてもらえませんか？
>   道に迷ってしまって・・・ちょっと教えてもらってもいいですか？  etc...

Comment: So I guess you don't need to say "道を(教えて...)" because it's implied, right?

Comment: Yeah... you'd probably leave it out, avoiding the repetition.

Comment: One other question, is it safe to omit "道に" from the beginning here? Does 迷う by itself sound too vague (like they are unable to decide what to do)?

Comment: @Locksleyu I think it would be understood from the context. I feel people say like 「すいません、ちょっと迷っちゃったんですけど、道(を)教えてもらってもいいですか」 in casual conversation.

Answer (score 5):

手伝う means ***doing*** something to help somebody do something.
In Japanese, 教える means not only teach but also ***tell***.

So, likewise, when you need a help doing your homework, asking to 手伝う turns out to be cheating, and so you usually ask someone to 教える something you have a problem with: 教えてください, 教えてもらえますか, 教えていただけますか, etc.

So, at work or at home doing house chores, when you ask co-workers or family members for help, the word is 手伝ってください, 手伝ってくれませんか, or casually 手伝ってね, or in a little commanding tone with still casual air, suitable to talk to your kids, 手伝ってちょうだい.